# Should we do cardio each day.?

Tags: cardio

I am 87 Kg with height of 5'11. My body fat percent is ~ 27%. I want to cut some fat and gain good muscles.

I have recently joined a gym where the trainer has told me to do treadmill, cross trainer & cycle (cardio) each day with 10mins of duration each. He has also planned a gym schedule for me which include 2 days of full cardio and abdominal exercise out of total 6 days.

I don't really feel like doing cardio each day when my schedule also include 2 days cardio. Also I go to gym in the evening and I think doing cardio after weight training is good but trainer suggested me to do cardio before starting the weight training.

Should I do cardio each day and that to before weight training. ? Thanks

Comment: Did he say why you should?

Comment: @DeeV No but I thought because I have extra fat on my body so doing cardio will reduce it.

Comment: You virtually can't build muscle and lose fat at the same time. Losing weight means burning more calories than you consume - this makes building muscle very difficult. Muscle is built optimally when you are storing more calories than you burn. Each of these should(/must) be tackled one at a time. This is why professional bodybuilders, for example, will pack on weight in the offseason, build their muscle optimally, then slowly cut weight/fat while trying to retain the muscle they have built for competition time.

Comment: @doodlebob You're talking about elite people trying to build massive amounts of muscle and stay around 8% body fat. Someone at 27% body fat can certainly change their body composition through cardio and strength training (with a focus on strength training)

Comment: @Dan I'm using that as an example. The same concept applies to everybody. And yes, you can certainly change your body composition through doing cardio and strength training - you just wont be able to build muscle mass. Doing both is important so you **maintain** as much muscle as possible while cutting, but, as I said, you wont **build** muscle if you're losing fat/weight.

Comment: @doodlebob - that’s simply incorrect. People do it all the time, I’ve even personally built muscle while losing fat. Saying it isn’t possible is just wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cardio can certainly help to burn some additional calories. And when you expend more calories than you consume, weight loss occurs. Your goals, your time, and your recovery are things to consider with the notion of daily cardio. So here’s a short list of pros and cons for different types of cardio to help you decide.

“HIIT”, High Intensity Interval Training

- (pro) Requires minimal time (<20 mins)
- (pro) Builds cardiovascular endurance.
- (con) Requires a lot of effort.
- (con) Requires more recovery.

“LISS”, Low Intensity Steady State

- (pro) Requires minimal effort.
- (pro) Requires minimal recovery.
- (con) Requires a lot of time (>30 mins)
- (con) Limited cardiovascular benefits.

Moderate Intensity

- (pro) Can help with specific athletic goals.
- (con) Takes cons from HIIT and LISS.

Your capacity to speak is an easy reference point for which type of cardio you are doing if you aren’t sure for some reason. For HIIT (or high intensity cardio in general) you shouldn’t be able to speak more than a singular quick word here and there. For moderate intensity, it’s somewhere between broken sentences and complete sentences with difficulty. For LISS, it’s complete sentences with minimal difficulty.

You’ll notice that I didn’t mention calories in any of the types of cardio, that’s because given enough time they are all equal. You don’t want your activities to exceed your body’s capacity to recover, nor do you (typically) want to spend all of your free time exercising. So again, your goals, time, and recovery capacity should guide your decision. It should also be noted here that cardio isn’t strictly necessary for weight loss, eating slightly less can have the same effect as cardio on your calorie balance over the course of a day.

The answer to “Should You” is simply “It Depends”, but it’s also not necessary in the first place. Having a warmup before your workout is useful, but that warmup doesn’t need to be cardio (ideally your warmup should hit the muscles that will be worked however). Strength Training is arguably better for fat loss than cardio anyway, but that shouldn’t discount the value of cardio. Just experiment and see what works best for you and your goals, good luck!